# Remember password and autocomplete passwords in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching in the web about this and found a lot of examples to achieve this, but none of it has worked to me, what i want its to make browsers ask to save your password and when the username is given, autocomplete the password. I have this:

```
<form id="LoginForm">
       <label>UserName: </label>
       <input id="user" type="text" name="user" maxlength="16" class="inputTextLogIn"/>                             
       <label>Password: </label>
        <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" maxlength="16" class="inputTextLogIn"/>
        <button id='loginButton' href='index.php?module=welcome' type='submit'>Entrar</button>
</form>
```

Javascript code to validate:

```
$("#LoginForm").validate({
                event: "blur",
                rules: {
                    'user': {
                        required: true,
                        maxlength: 50
                    },
                    'pass': {
                        required: true,
                        maxlength: 12
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    'user': "Usuario debe ser válido",
                    'pass': "Contraseña debe ser válida"
                },
                errorElement: "label",
                submitHandler: function(form){
                    return doClick($("#loginButton"), $(form).serialize());
                }
        });
```

The first time, the browser ask for save the password and also autocomplete it, next times, it doesnt, what am i missing???

Comment: you should make sure that autocomplete is turned on

Comment: _“what i want its to make browsers ask to save your password and when the username is given, autocomplete the password.”_ – sorry, but isn’t that an already built-in feature in modern browsers? I don’t see why you would want to implement anything manually here …

Comment: yes i think its a built in feature for most of the browsers.

Comment: @CBroe I know its already a feature in browsers, but my form doesnt call that feature...

Answer (score 1):

@Subbu was on the right path, and you are very close...

Html5 has a specific tag that is used to tell the browser that the field is autocomplete-able. Just turn on Autocomplete in your form tag, and it will turn it on for all fields.

Here's what it looks like using your form:

```
<form id="LoginForm" autocomplete="on">
       <label>UserName: </label>
       <input id="user" type="text" name="user" maxlength="16" class="inputTextLogIn"/>                             
       <label>Password: </label>
       <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" maxlength="16" class="inputTextLogIn"/>
       <button id='loginButton' href='index.php?module=welcome' type='submit'>Entrar</button>
</form>
```

Then, whenever the user will come back to the page, it will populate the username, and password. If, for some reason, you didn't want a field to populate, just put autocomplete to off, like so:

```
<input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" maxlength="16" class="inputTextLogIn" autocomplete="off"/>
```